# Term or phrase representing all objects inside of a parent object

Tags: nouns, terminology

I am programming an iOS App and I have an alert popup that asks a user to confirm the deletion of a directory.  I want to show the following message:

```
"DIR is not empty!
 Deleting this folder will permanently remove all 
 [SUB-ITEMS/SUBDIRECTORIES/COMPRISING ITEMS/?????]!"
```

but I cannot think of the proper term for items (files/folders/etc) inside a directory.

I would greatly appreciate any help finding the correct term or phrase for this message.

<sub>PostScript: Are "*subdirectories*" and "*subfiles*" proper english words?</sub>

Comment: "Subdirectories" is proper, or at least, proper enough to suit me. I've certainly seen the word used pretty widely. Contrarily, "subfiles" for some reason, seems strange to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write

> Deleting this folder will permanently remove all its **contents**.

Comment: Drat, ninja'd by Jasper Loy. Definitely agree. "Contents" says it best.

Comment: I award +1 for the answer, and a bonus +0.5 for putting the word "its" between "all" and "contents".   Unfortunately, I had to round this down :-)

Comment: This is good, but "contents" makes me personally think of the data inside of a single file.  I'm not sure, but would this lead users to think they are deleting a file instead of a directory and all of its descendants?

Comment: Cool, thanks!  It's funny how things like this are sometimes the hardest part of programming :).

Answer (score 2):

You can't go wrong with

```
"DIR is not empty!
 Deleting this folder will permanently remove all 
 [files and folders]!"
```

Comment: This may be ambiguous; the first thing I thought when I read this is that it *could* mean removing all files/folders period, not just the ones inside said dir.  I appreciate the suggestion but I'm going to go with Jasper's answer.

Comment: I didn't mean to be so smarmy about it.  I totally understand.